# Execute die(); from another script

Tags: php, exit

So how i can exectute `die();` from one php script to another? ex.:

*1.php*

```
<?php
  require("2.php");
  sleep(2);
  send_die_to_another_php("Success!", "2.php"); // Magic code
?>
```

*2.php*

```
<?php
    sleep(10);
?>
```

Comment: Are you trying to have it run for only 2 seconds instead of 10 seconds?

Comment: Yes. It's just example. I have a different code.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. PHP is single threaded; when you get to this line:

```
require("2.php");
```

that `sleep(10)` in `2.php` (and everything else there) will get executed before anything else in `1.php` is run, because the `require()` call doesn't return until its target file is fully evaluated.